# OutOfMemory error when writing large data from PostgreSQL to Vertica using PySpark and JDBC

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

I'm reading data of over 20GB from a PostgreSQL database using PySpark and JDBC. However, when I attempt to write this data to a Vertica database using JDBC, the program fails with an OutOfMemory error. I've monitored the memory usage and determined that the executor memory is insufficient.

How can I write the data in chunks to avoid this issue? I've tried using repartition but it hasn't resolved the problem. Here's my code:

```py
# Function to read data from the source
def read_data(spark_session, properties_dict):
    """
    Read data from the source specified in the properties file using the configurations provided.
    """
    try:
        logger.info('Reading data from source...')
        source_read_options = {
            "driver": properties_dict['driver'],
            "url": properties_dict['url'],
            "user": properties_dict['user'],
            "password": properties_dict['password'],
            "dbtable": properties_dict['table']['dbtable'],
        }
        source_df = spark_session.read \
            .format(properties_dict['format']) \
            .options(**source_read_options) \
            .load()

        #print(source_df.count())
        logger.info('Completed')
        return source_df
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error reading data from source: {e}")
        raise
```

```py
# Function to write data to the target
def write_data(source_df,spark_session, properties_dict):
    """
    Write the DataFrame 'source_df' to the target specified in the properties file using the configurations provided.
    """
    try:
        logger.info('Writing data to target...')
        target_write_options = {
            "driver": properties_dict['target_data']['driver'],
            "url": properties_dict['target_data']['url'],
            "user": properties_dict['target_data']['user'],
            "password": properties_dict['target_data']['password'],
            "dbtable": properties_dict['target_data']['table']['dbtable'],
            "createTableColumnTypes": properties_dict['target_data']['table']['columnTypes'],
        }         
        source_df.write \
            .format(properties_dict['target_data']['format']) \
            .options(**target_write_options) \
            .mode("append") \
            .save()
       
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error writing data to target: {e}")
        raise
```

I tried reading over 20GB of data from a PostgreSQL database using PySpark and JDBC and then writing this data to a Vertica database. I expected the data to be written seamlessly without any issues.

After reading the data from PostgreSQL, I attempted to write it to Vertica. Given my experience with both databases and the tools I was using, I expected the data transfer to be smooth. However, during the write process, the program crashed, and I received an OutOfMemory error. On further inspection, I realized that the executor memory was insufficient. I also tried to use the repartition method in hopes of dividing the data and writing it in smaller chunks, but this approach did not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you post your "repartition" attempt?